# How to access parent window variables in child when using iframe in Angular

Tags: angular, iframe

We have different angular microapps. I have to call another angular app using iframe.
So far i am able to open the app using iframe from app1.
But not able to access App1 data in App2 component class.

Here's my code
App1: app.component.html

```
<iframe id="inlineFrameExample"
title="Inline Frame Example"
src="http://localhost:4200/offer-onboarding">
</iframe>
```

> App1: app.component.ts

> parentVariable : string = "I am from parent";

App2: app.component.ts

> How can i read parentVariable in App2 component class

I tried @ViewChild and @Input it's not working.

Comment: Are they both on the same domain/port? 
Also, a browser or iframe is a sandbox, one angular app doesn’t have (direct) acces to the other scope so things like @Input or even shared services are not possible. You’re only routes are postMessages or polling localStorage (or shared server state). I’d really reconsider the iframe route, it pretty much sucks 

Comment: I am testing it in my localhost. And i am able to get App2 inside App1 iframe. but can't access it's variables. idea is App1 will inject some auth code to App2. in App2 i have to capture this auth code. And i am afraid i have to go with iFrame as other teams are going same route.

Comment: Have a look at postMessage..

Comment: You could try passing info through the `window` object as well